# Does selenium IDE require internet to record and playback?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-ide

I installed selenium ide extension in chrome for recording and playback. I wanted to record some testing using swagger on my local host, so for trial and understanding purpose, I disabled internet and ran selenium ide recorder and then tried to run the recording, but it is not able to. When I turn on the internet, it does. I am trying to understand why internet is required. Is there some library or something which selenium ide use from internet?. I am trying to understand why selenium is dependent on internet to do its job?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Katalon and UI.Vision Selenium IDE have the "Runs offline" flag in the Chrome store, so in principle it can work. But the classic Selenium IDE does not have this flag. This is a setting in the extension manifest.